# How to create the given html format using Javascript dom?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, containers

I have to get the data printed like the below format using document object model. I am having the problem in creating the below html.

```
name1       name2       name3
50          48          56

name4       name5       name6
52          58          49
```

example using below format:

```
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  var row = document.createElement("row");
```

Comment: there is no domelement called 'row' have you even looked at [html5 tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/table.html) spec

Comment: Take a look at createElement, appendChild, and html table spec as mentioned by @birdspider

Comment: Where is the data stored at the moment? Is it in an array, an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tr` instead of `row`

```
var row0 = document.createElement("tr");
```

Here is a quick start for what you want to do:

```js
var table = document.createElement("table");
var row0 = document.createElement("tr");
var a0 = document.createElement("td");
a0.textContent = "name1";
var a1 = document.createElement("td");
a1.textContent = "name2";
var a2 = document.createElement("td");
a2.textContent = "name3";

var row1 = document.createElement("tr");
var b0 = document.createElement("td");
b0.textContent = "50";
var b1 = document.createElement("td");
b1.textContent = "48";
var b2 = document.createElement("td");
b2.textContent = "56";

row0.appendChild(a0);
row0.appendChild(a1);
row0.appendChild(a2);

row1.appendChild(b0);
row1.appendChild(b1);
row1.appendChild(b2);

table.appendChild(row0);
table.appendChild(row1);

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a  element

```
var table = document.createElement("table");
```

Create an empty  element and add it to the 1st position of the table:

```
var row = table.insertRow(0);
```

Insert new cells ( elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new"  element:

```
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
```

// Add some text to the new cells:

```
cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
```

[See reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `insertRow` function of `table` to create new row.

find the below code:

```
  var table = document.createElement("table");

  //to create first row
    var row = table.insertRow(0);

  // first row columns
    var col = row.insertCell(0);
    col.textContent = "name1";

    col = row.insertCell(1);
    col.textContent = "name2";

    col = row.insertCell(2);
    col.textContent = "name3";

  // for second row
    row = table.insertRow(1);

  // for second row columns 
    col = row.insertCell(0);
    col.textContent = "50";

    col = row.insertCell(1);
    col.textContent = "48";

    col = row.insertCell(2);
    col.textContent = "56";

  document.body.appendChild(table);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cxLnbcsj/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have your data stored in an object you can do this programmatically:

```
var data = {
    name1: 50,
    name2: 48,
    name3: 56,
    name4: 52,
    name5: 58,
    name6: 49
};

function buildTable(data) {

    // grab the headings from the object
    var headings = Object.keys(data);
    var cells = [], rows = [];

    // for each heading, push it and its data value into the cell array
    headings.forEach(function (heading, i) {
        var value = data[headings[i]];
        cells.push('<td>' + heading + '<br/>' + value + '</td>');

        // when we reach the end of the row, brace the cell data with
        // row tags, and clear the cells array
        if ((i + 1) % 3 === 0) {
            rows = rows.concat('<tr>' + cells.join('') + '</tr>');
            cells = [];
        }
    });

    // return the complete table html
    return '<table>' + rows.join('') + '</table>'
}

// grab the body tag and insert the table html as the first child
var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', buildTable(data));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z3oqvxmt/)